How to import datfiles with filter based on datetimepicker with list dapper in VB.NET
I'm Trying to import datfiles with filter based on datetimepicker with list dapper in VB.NET
means there are 2 controls, namely DateTimePicker1 & DateTimePicker2
I use 2 control dateTimePicker because it states one period which is the start date and end date.
DateTimePicker1 => 18-Mar-24
DateTimePicker2 <= 19-Mar-24
The code below I created please guide me so that I can make the list dapper  filter with datetimepicker
Thanks
   Protected Sub ReadDat()
        Dim fName As String = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\TestFile"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Dat files(*.Dat)|*.Dat"
        OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
            Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(fName)
            Dim datfiles As List(Of datfiles) = New List(Of datfiles)()
 For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lines(i).Trim()) Then
                    Dim data As String() = lines(i).Trim().Split(CType(vbTab, Char()))
                    datfiles.Add(New datfiles() With {
                        .ID = data(0),
                        .DATE = data(1).ToString().Split(" "c)(0),
                        .TIME = data(1).ToString().Split(" "c)(1),
                        .FP = data(2),
                        .INOUT = If(data(3).ToString() = "0", "IN", "OUT"),
                        .OTHERS1 = data(4),
                        .OTHERS2 = data(5)
                         })
 End If
            Next
            ' Use the DataTable to populate the DataGridView.
            BunifuDataGridView1.Visible = True
            BunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = datfiles
            BunifuDataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    End Sub


`Public Class datfiles
Public Property ID() As Integer
Public Property [DATE]() As Date
Public Property TIME() As String
Public Property FP() As String
<DisplayName("IN/OUT")>
Public Property INOUT() As String
Public Property OTHERS1() As String
Public Property OTHERS2() As Integer

End Class`
sample dat files :
     5010   2024-03-16 06:59:10 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-16 07:11:00 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-16 16:32:09 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-16 16:33:19 1   1   0   0 
     5010   2024-03-17 06:59:10 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-17 07:11:00 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-17 16:32:09 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-17 16:33:19 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-18 06:59:10 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-18 07:11:00 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-18 16:32:09 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-18 16:33:19 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-19 07:05:15 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-19 07:31:19 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-19 16:30:50 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-19 16:31:12 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-20 07:05:15 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-20 07:31:19 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-20 16:30:50 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-20 16:31:12 1   1   0   0

Result from Code
ID      DATE        TIME        FP IN/OUT  OTHERS1 OTHERS2
5010    16-Mar-24   06:59:10    1   IN        0      0
5014    16-Mar-24   07:11:00    1   IN        0      0
5014    16-Mar-24   16:32:09    1   OUT       0      0
5010    16-Mar-24   16:33:19    1   OUT       0      0
5010    17-Mar-24   06:59:10    1   IN        0      0
5014    17-Mar-24   07:11:00    1   IN        0      0
5014    17-Mar-24   16:32:09    1   OUT       0      0
5010    17-Mar-24   16:33:19    1   OUT       0      0
5010    18-Mar-24   06:59:10    1   IN        0      0
5014    18-Mar-24   07:11:00    1   IN        0      0
5014    18-Mar-24   16:32:09    1   OUT       0      0
5010    18-Mar-24   16:33:19    1   OUT       0      0
5010    19-Mar-24   07:05:15    1   IN        0      0
5014    19-Mar-24   07:31:19    1   IN        0      0
5014    19-Mar-24   16:30:50    1   OUT       0      0
5010    19-Mar-24   16:31:12    1   OUT       0      0
5010    20-Mar-24   07:05:15    1   IN        0      0
5014    20-Mar-24   07:31:19    1   IN        0      0
5014    20-Mar-24   16:30:50    1   OUT       0      0
5010    20-Mar-24   16:31:12    1   OUT       0      0

Desired Result

ID      DATE        TIME        FP IN/OUT  OTHERS1 OTHERS2
5010    18-Mar-24   06:59:10    1   IN       0      0
5014    18-Mar-24   07:11:00    1   IN       0      0
5014    18-Mar-24   16:32:09    1   OUT      0      0
5010    18-Mar-24   16:33:19    1   OUT      0      0
5010    19-Mar-24   07:05:15    1   IN       0      0
5014    19-Mar-24   07:31:19    1   IN       0      0
5014    19-Mar-24   16:30:50    1   OUT      0      0
5010    19-Mar-24   16:31:12    1   OUT      0      0


